# org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG in api calling

Tags: android, soap, asmx, android-ksoap2

I am new bee in android. I am trying parse data using soap api. Following is my snippet code. When I run the project I am getting following error can any one help me with this? Following is my snippet code. I am not able to find the issue what exactly I am facing. sorry for bad english.

Error

> W/System.err: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected:
>   START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope
>   (position:START_TAG @4:44 in java.io.InputStreamReader@7f5b56a)

Code

```
public class GetReport extends Activity {

    private static final String NAMESPACE = "https://www.myweb.co.ke/Wt/"; // com.service.ServiceImpl
    private static final String URL = "https://www.myweb.co.ke/Wt/webtask.asmx";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "GetProductListing";
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE+METHOD_NAME;
    private String webResponse = "";
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private Thread thread;

    private TextView textView1;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(1);
        setContentView(R.layout.test_demo);
        textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ttte);



        startWebAccess("title");

    }

    public void startWebAccess(String a) {
        final String aa = a;
        thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Log.d("Req value0R", "Starting...");// log.d is used for
                    // debug
                    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

                   /* request.addProperty("ClientCode", "64396");
                    request.addProperty("key", "Om$@!#@M^#R");*/

                    request.addProperty("User Name", "1234");
                    request.addProperty("Password", "4321");

                    Log.d("Req value1", request.toString());

                    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                    envelope.dotNet = true;
                    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

                    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(
                            URL);
                    androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
                    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                    SoapObject objectResult = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
                    webResponse = objectResult.toString();
                    System.out.println("response: " + webResponse);

                } catch (SoapFault sp) {

                    sp.getMessage();
                    System.out.println("error = " + sp.getMessage());

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("problem8");
                    e.printStackTrace();

                    webResponse = "Connection/Internet problem";
                }

                handler.post(createUI);
            }
        };

        thread.start();
    }

    final Runnable createUI = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            if (webResponse != null) {

                textView1.setText(webResponse);
            } else {
                webResponse = "No data provided presently";
                textView1.setText(webResponse);
            }
        }
    };

}
```